# Adapter is not updated when a new LiveData item is added

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, listadapter

In my ViewModel, I create a mutableList and observe it in Activity using LiveData,  I pass the list to ListAdapter. But when I add a new item to the list using the method, LiveData doesn't update the list automatically. The list will only be updated if `notifyDataSetChanged()` is explicitly called.

How to make LiveData work without `notifyDataSetChanged()` method?

My ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _listWindows = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Window>>().apply {
        value = mutableListOf(Window())
    }

    fun addWindow(window: Window) {
        _listWindows.value?.add(window)
        _listWindows.value = _listWindows.value
    }

    val list: LiveData<MutableList<Window>> = _listWindows
}
```

Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
    private val adapterWindows = AdapterWindows()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java).also {
            binding.viewmodel = it
        }

        with(binding) {
            recyclerView.apply {
                adapter = adapterWindows
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            }
        }

        viewModel.list.observe(this, Observer {
            adapterWindows.submitList(it)
        })

        binding.buttonAddWindow.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.addWindow(Window())
        }
    }
```

Data Class:

```
data class Window(val length: String = "", val width: String = "") {
}
```

Comment: you cant update the list without notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: You may do, submitList(null) then submitList(newList) for preventing implicitly notify call.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Tried to find an error in my code))